# How to save fmod core sound data to a mp3 file that contains custom dsp effects added to it?

Tags: android, lame, fmod

I am using fmod core for my android studio project in kotlin to add dsp effects like echo, delay and reverb to imported sound. I am saving the sound to a raw file and converting it to a mp3 file using LAME library. The audio file is saved successfully but it has no dsp effects I added before to it. The original sound data I got from sound->lock before adding effects to sound and after is the same. How to make sure the exported file has those effects applied to it?

I looked into DSP related functions in fmod core function reference https://www.fmod.com/docs/2.02/api/core-api-dsp.html . Maybe I need to use DSP::getParameterData to get the data or dsp callbacks and add them to saved file?